# Add node.js modules for use with Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I believe I'm running into the same issue as described in [this earlier posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047246/how-to-include-the-azure-sdk-for-azure-nodejs-functions), but after following the "official" instructions from [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management), I'm still getting the following error when my Node.js code attempts to run as an Azure Functions trigger:

```
2018-02-20T20:53:43.527 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.NewMP3FileTrigger. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: Cannot find module 'azure-storage'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
```

This is the very first line in my code, which I believe is what's failing:

```js
var azure = require('azure-storage');
```

As far as I can tell, adding the package seemed to work via these steps:
- get the contents of the package.json file from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/package.json) (which looks legit).
- Using the Azure diagnostic console, placed the package.json file in the wwwroot folder.
- ran `npm install` in the console window.

It ran for some time, and when it was done, there was a very sizeable node_modules now in that same folder.  I did note that it generate a number of warnings like the following example, but not sure if these matter:

> *npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue*

Actually surprised that I need to add any modules for Microsoft services to any Azure environment as I would have thought they would be provided by default, but there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't copy `package.json` from the `azure-storage-node` repository. Instead, your `package.json` should simply reference `azure-storage` as dependency, e.g.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-storage": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

After `npm install` make sure that `node_modules` folder contains `azure-storage`.

P.S. Be sure to have a look at Storage bindings for Azure Functions, maybe you don't have to use SDK directly (depends on the use case).